# Fast way to detect numbers on prepaid cards

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I'm trying to detect the numbers on the prepaid cards like Vodafone. I'm looking for a fast way and easy way to do that. So I plan to use the Fast CV because it is optimized for ARM with neon support, and also would like to do a simple NCC with the characters to predefined images, and not detect the images at real time, just would like to take to capture an image then do the analysis. I would like to know the process to detect just the characters from the card. Is it just simple threshold, the find contours ?

Comment: Is there a barcode on the same side of the card as the numbers? If there is and it is printed using the same technology (inkjet/thermal) as the numbers, then the barcode would be able to define the location, rotation and scale of the numbers. Having a barcode, would be like having a ruler printed on the card.

Comment: @FredF yes, so detect the barcode and the numbers down it, then ?

Comment: That would be my approach. The second part of what I posted was to determine of the barcode was imaged along with the readable text of it the barcode was printed using a different technology. A UPC code would likely be printed with a plate, while the numbers printed with imaging. Use a magnifying glass. If the barcode is imaged, then the barcode and numbers would be exactly spaced from each other, while if printed with different technologies, they will only be closely matched, not exactly matched. Or check a few cards and compare placement exactness to the barcode.